# Pass test case input and output data in html report in python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, django-unittest

I am newbie to python and and unitesting. I am generating a report with testcase assertion input and status , but i want to show to user with testcase input data and output data in htmltestcase report

PLease help me on this.

Comment: In which format do you want report ?

Comment: testcasename, testcaseinput,testcaseoutput,status of testcase(pass/fail) in report.

Comment: in excel or word format ?

Comment: html format report